# Use get_pages() before another plugin modifies it

Tags: plugins, wp-query, pages

In my little plugin I am using get_pages() to get some specific pages. Important is the usage of "child_of" and a custom field key.

```
$pages = get_pages([
    'child_of' => 206, //Gets children and grandchildren
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'meta_key' => 'os_class_page_type',
]);
```

Now there is another plugin in my WP installation (DigiMember) which blocks pages to users which do not have access to the page.

**The big problem**: Digimember also filters the "get_pages" function so I can't use it to receive blocked pages. But I really need that to create some kind of overview of these pages.

I tried to call get_pages() earlier but it's not working before 'plugins_loaded' action is called. So I can't use it before DigiMember modifies it.

How can I used get_pages before it gets modified?

I could use WP_Query, but for WP_Query calls 'child_of' does not exist (I still have no idea why). But I really need to get all children and grandchildren. Using get_pages() does that perfectly - when it works.

Any ideas what I can do? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
Okay, I am using WP_Query for now, because it is not filtered by the other plugin. In this case I can't get the grandchildren (without doing extra loops) but I can work with that for now. I'm still interested in a better solution (which allows me to use less queries to wp).

Comment: Use the `post_parent` parameter in WP_Query. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters

Comment: I tried that but `post_parent` does not return grandchildren, it only returns direct children.

Comment: If the other plugin provides hooks, you can - in your function - first unhook whatever they've hooked, then run your code, then re-hook it, so that that plugin's modifications are only prevented within your own code.

Comment: I tried to remove the filter they added using `remove_filter` but that did not change anything. Furthermore I would like to have a solution that does not need to unhook plugin specific functions etc. :/